# How to change bug template invoked from test excution

Tags: templates, customization, workitem, tfs-workitem, microsoft-test-manager

I am using MTM 2010 and I need to change the bug template that is populated from the Test Result form or from the test case execution (I believe that both uses the same template).

Important to note that when you create a test case from these two places the template is not the same as you get when you make from the new button. The only difference is that the textbox "Steps to Reproduce" populates the steps from the "Test Case".

I already changed the bug template that is populated from the NEW button. I did it using the Process Editor and I added html code there. So when I create a new bug from the "NEW" button the template populates the bug template with the "Steps to Reproduce" textbox with some words that I added as script template, just as a reminder.

Explained all this, what I need is that MTM populates the bug invoked from Test Result form and from the test case execution with my script template plus the steps from the "Test Case" automatically added.

I need something like this:

Anyone knows where and how I have to change the code to make this possible?

Comment: It is the same template, its just that the steps to reproduce field gets filled out based on the context. I don't think what you want is possible as whatever you add to that field will be overridden. What problem are you trying to solve? There might be another way to get you the result you want.

Comment: Thanks! It is very possible that the info on that textbox is overwritten. I wish I could change that and to have my script template.

The solution I'm using now is copy and paste the script template. It would be very desirable to me that this automatically appears. Because I am implementing testing in a company that has spent 15 years without it. And I'm the only tester. All other people to test they are geologists, chemicals, petrochemicals and are highly resistant to change and adopt testing methodologies. Then I need the tools are clear and show no ambiguities.

Comment: What are you inserting into the Steps to Reproduce field? Could you perhaps insert that into a different location? The Steps to Reproduce field is very specific; altering it isn't recommended as it can have unintended consequences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am only inserting text, a text script as a guide:


Description: //

Steps to reproduce the error: //

Expected result: //

Current result: //


It is a guide that they must complete. Please take into account that they are very picky so I thought this as a way to ensure they complete all required minimum data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think inserting text or changing the default value for the Steps to Reproduce field is going to give you what you need, as depending on how the bug work item gets created that field may or may not be overridden.

However, you may be able to accomplish what you seek by instead creating two new fields, one for current value and one for expected value and making them required. This way they will not be able to create a bug without supplying the needed information. The fields would look something like:

```
<FIELD name="Expected Value" refname="Company.ExpectedValue" type="String">
  <REQUIRED />
</FIELD>
```